# QML-Change data in Image Details tab properties

Tags: qt, qml

I use Qt version 5.6.0 with qml from windows 8.1.I want to set metadata for captured images in QML. I've tried the following code, the program runs on desktop takes the picture and saves it. After I open it up with Preview and check the metadata... and nothing special there (no Author key or cameraModel or title , ...).

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    metaData.cameraModel: "lenovo"                              
    imageCapture {                              
        onImageCaptured: {
        camera.imageCapture.setMetadata(camera.metaData.title,"neda")
        camera.imageCapture.setMetadata("Title","neda")
        ...
        ...
 onImageMetadataAvailable:{
    setMetadata(key,value)
    console.log("Image Metadata Callback : "+key+" = "+value)
    setMetadata("Title","neda")
}


onClicked: {
    camera.imageCapture.setMetadata(camera.metaData.author, "neda")
    //or this code:
    camera.imageCapture.setMetadata("Author", "neda")
    //or this code:
    camera.metaData.author="neda"
    camera.imageCapture.capture()
```

**Update:**
I also tried to do that using QImageWriter as follows:

```
QImage image("c:/1.jpg");
QImageWriter writer("c:/11.png", "png");
writer.setText("Author", "neda");
writer.write(image);
```

But, none of my tries gave me any success (change data in Image Details tab properties). Any idea?

**Update**:
Save image:

```
#ifndef ImageSaver_H
#define ImageSaver_H
#include <QImage>
#include <QObject>
class QQuickItem;
class QString;
class ImageSaver : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
        explicit ImageSaver(QObject *parent = 0);
        ImageSaver(ImageSaver const&) = delete;
        ImageSaver& operator=(ImageSaver const&) = delete;

   public slots:
   void load(QString const &path);
   void loadAndSave(QString const &path);
   void save(QString const &path) const;

private:
QImage img_;
};
#endif // ImageSaver_H


#include "ImageSaver.h"
#include <QGraphicsObject>
#include <QImageWriter>
#include <QImageIOHandler>
ImageSaver::ImageSaver(QObject *parent) :
  QObject(parent)
{
}
void ImageSaver::load(QString const &path)
{
   img_.load(path);
}
void ImageSaver::loadAndSave(QString const &path)
{
   img_.load(path);
   img_.save(path);
}
void ImageSaver::save(const QString &path) const
{
 img_.save(path);
 QImageWriter writer(path, "png");
 if (writer.supportsOption(QImageIOHandler::Description))
 {
    writer.setText("Author", "Neda");
    writer.write(img_);
 }
}
```

main.qml:

```
imageSaver.save(path);
```

Comment: In your QML code example there is no function that saves the image. Maybe the problem is with how you save it?

Comment: One possibility may be that metaData properties are read-only, and are set by camera driver. You can try to run the code on a mobile device.